# SyncWarning: Failed to overwrite commands in Guild, Missing Access

Tags: python, discord

I've started receiving a warning (when I start the bot):

```
disnake\ext\commands\interaction_bot_base.py:733: SyncWarning: Failed to overwrite commands in <Guild id=889176263992963142> due to 403 Forbidden (error code: 50001): Missing Access
  warnings.warn(
```

Tried locating it, but the line this error supposedly occurs at is (the last one):

```py
async def _sync_application_command_permissions(self) -> None:
    # Assuming that permissions and commands are cached
    if not isinstance(self, disnake.Client):
        raise NotImplementedError(f"This method is only usable in disnake.Client subclasses")
```

The warning I've sent is the full message. I've also tried going back a few version, when I am sure that it didn't produce this warning, but it started appearing now.

The bot was invited with `applications.commands` scope included.

Library used is `disnake`, if someone could create a specific tag for it, that would be nice.

Answer (score 1):

The issue was, trying to access `test_guild` while not being present there (I've kicked the bot from one of two guilds it was at).

```py
bot = commands.Bot(
    command_prefix=commands.when_mentioned_or("!"), 
    test_guilds=[guild_id1, guild_id2], 
    intents=disnake.Intents.all()
)
```

Removing this extra guild solved the issue.

Comment: I have the same problem, but there is only one guild and the bot is present there. still the problem persists

Comment: I don't know what could be causing it, but maybe the permissions changed? The bot lost a role or something?

Comment: I forgot to re-add the bot with the applications.commands scope. Now it's working